# Not able to Iterate over objects

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation

I have a list of buttons on a web page. I am able to get the list of buttons by using the Get Class Name function. But I am not able to iterate over it.

Here is the code:

```html
<main role="main">
        <div class="wrapper">

        </div>

        <div class="wrapper wrapper-medium">


  <header>
    <h1>Unsubmitted Timesheets</h1>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="fl-left">
        <select name="" id="select-timeframe" class="hui-input"><option value="/missing_time/period/36/2018">05 Feb 2018 - 11 Feb 2018</option>
<option selected="selected" value="/missing_time/period/29/2018">This Week</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/22/2018">22 Jan 2018 - 28 Jan 2018</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/15/2018">15 Jan 2018 - 21 Jan 2018</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/8/2018">08 Jan 2018 - 14 Jan 2018</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/29/2018?all_weeks=1">- show all weeks -</option></select>
      </div>

        <div class="fl-right">
          <button type="button" class="hui-button" data-open-dialog="email-reminder-dialog">
              <i data-icon="check-green"></i>
              Sending Reminder Every Friday
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
      <form id="missing-time-form" action="/missing_time/reminders?return_to=%2Fmissing_time%2Fperiod%2F29%2F2018" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="?"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="YmA26BT5bHy1NQKiKks+j/nKl5saFnF2fAmp/Oy6zuWANPkuuMLYTZDtdZHa/7TNh2CcUx5R2e0FsPWOxThVoQ==">
        <table id="unsubmitted-timesheets" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>
                Team Members<br>
                <small>
                  Select:
                  <button type="button" class="button-link js-toggle-all-users">All</button>
                  /
                  <button type="button" class="button-link js-toggle-no-users">None</button>
                </small>
              </th>
              <th class="text-right">Time</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="has-clickable-table-rows" data-required-checkboxes="You must select at least one recipient.">
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1964976]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Alexander Cubillos" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1964976]" id="send_reminder_1964976">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1964976"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Alexander Cubillos
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1964976" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  24:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1964976" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1964976">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1840318]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Allain Dollete" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1840318]" id="send_reminder_1840318">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1840318"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Allain Dollete
                  <label for="send_reminder_1840318" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  24:30
                  <label for="send_reminder_1840318" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1840318">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1882520]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Anil Khemchandani" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1882520]" id="send_reminder_1882520">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1882520"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Anil Khemchandani
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1882520" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1882520" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1882520">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1028098]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Anna Jhaveri" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1028098]" id="send_reminder_1028098">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1028098"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Anna Jhaveri
                  <label for="send_reminder_1028098" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1028098" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1028098">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1399194]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Chaitanya Potluri" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1399194]" id="send_reminder_1399194">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1399194"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Chaitanya Potluri
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1399194" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  40:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1399194" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1399194">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1908612]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Daniel Pedraza Mena" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1908612]" id="send_reminder_1908612">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1908612"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Daniel Pedraza Mena
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1908612" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  16:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1908612" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1908612">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1806244]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Danny Davidson" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1806244]" id="send_reminder_1806244">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1806244"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Danny Davidson
                  <label for="send_reminder_1806244" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  40:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1806244" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1806244">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1918323]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Debbie Fink" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1918323]" id="send_reminder_1918323">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1918323"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Debbie Fink
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1918323" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1918323" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1918323">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1937598]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Dickson Law" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1937598]" id="send_reminder_1937598">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1937598"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Dickson Law
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1937598" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1937598" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1937598">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1221855]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Divyang Patel" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1221855]" id="send_reminder_1221855">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1221855"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Divyang Patel
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1221855" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1221855" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1221855">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1218884]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Hetal Desai" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1218884]" id="send_reminder_1218884">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1218884"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Hetal Desai
                  <label for="send_reminder_1218884" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1218884" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1218884">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1908572]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Hiren Changela" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1908572]" id="send_reminder_1908572">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1908572"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Hiren Changela
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1908572" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  8:20
                  <label for="send_reminder_1908572" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1908572">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1457227]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Jayson Greenberg" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1457227]" id="send_reminder_1457227">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1457227"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Jayson Greenberg
                  <label for="send_reminder_1457227" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1457227" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1457227">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
                              <td class="text-right">
                  25:11
                  <label for="send_reminder_1955711" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1955711">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1819930]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Ranga Beeram" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1819930]" id="send_reminder_1819930">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1819930"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Ranga Beeram
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1819930" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1819930" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1819930">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1198081]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Ratnakumar Paleru" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1198081]" id="send_reminder_1198081">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1198081"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Ratnakumar Paleru
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1198081" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  40:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1198081" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1198081">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1250162]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Ricky Raghavan" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1250162]" id="send_reminder_1250162">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1250162"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Ricky Raghavan
                  <label for="send_reminder_1250162" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  43:01
                  <label for="send_reminder_1250162" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1250162">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1983564]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Robert Pearl" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1983564]" id="send_reminder_1983564">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1983564"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Robert Pearl
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1983564" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1983564" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1983564">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1491814]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Roeleke van Munster" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1491814]" id="send_reminder_1491814">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1491814"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Roeleke van Munster
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1491814" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  24:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1491814" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1491814">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1567062]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Suhil Jisahebwala" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1567062]" id="send_reminder_1567062">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1567062"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Suhil Jisahebwala
                  <label for="send_reminder_1567062" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  34:45
                  <label for="send_reminder_1567062" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1567062">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1938412]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Thomas Daly" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1938412]" id="send_reminder_1938412">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1938412"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Thomas Daly
                  <label for="send_reminder_1938412" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:15
                  <label for="send_reminder_1938412" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1938412">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1042800]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Tosha Mehta" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1042800]" id="send_reminder_1042800">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1042800"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Tosha Mehta
                  <label for="send_reminder_1042800" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1042800" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1042800">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1330499]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Ujjaval Bhavsar" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1330499]" id="send_reminder_1330499">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1330499"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>

</form>    </div>
  </div>
      </main>
```

I target the buttons using the class name "hui-button hui-button-tiny" and this is what I have tried:

```
($ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("hui-button hui-button-tiny") |
    Select-Object -First 1).Click()
```

So with the above statement I am able to click on the 1st button of the page. Replacing "first" with "last" would allow me to click on the last button of the page.
But this not exactly what I want. I would ideally like to click on one button at a time go to the respective page and then come back to the main page. From there go to the next button and the process repeats until all the buttons have been visited. The problem is I am not able to iterate over the buttons. This is what I have tried doing:

```
#$View_Timesheet_Object=$ie.document.getElementsByClassName("hui-button hui-button-tiny")
for ($i=0; $i -le $View_Timesheet_Object.Length; $i++) {
    ($View_Timesheet_Object | Select-Object $i).Click()
    #Perform Actions on the second page
    #Navigate back to the main page
    $ie.Navigate(Main Page)
}
```

I get this message:

```
Select-Object : Cannot convert System.Int32 to one of the following types
{System.String,  System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
At C:\Users\rr\Documents\PowerShell\ie6.ps1:37 char:26
+ ($View_Timesheet_Object |Select-Object $i).click()
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectComm
```

I tried checking the count by executing this command

```
Write-Host $View_Timesheet_Object.Count
```

but it always returns 0.

Comment: `$ie.document.getElementsByClassName("...") | ForEach-Object {$_.Click()}`?

Comment: `($View_Timesheet_Object | Select-Object -Index $i).Click()`?

Comment: @JosefZ  I get this error Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At C:\Users\rr\Documents\PowerShell\ie6.ps1:30 char:1
+ $ie.document.getElementsByClassName("hui-button hui-button-tiny") | F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I get this error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At C:\Users\rr\Documents\PowerShell\ie6.ps1:59 char:1
+ $element=$ie.document.getElementByID("hui-button submit-link js-toggl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException